# Start 2 webservers in c#

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-3.0, blazor, kestrel-http-server, blazor-client-side

Is there a way to start 2 web app projects simultaneously?  Something like this:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        BlazorApp.Program.Main(null);
        MyWebApi.Program.Main(null);
        // ... maybe start other services...
    }
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio you can set multiple startup projects by right click on the solution in the **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties**. refer to [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019); In CLI, dotnet run will not have this capability for you, since it works in the context of a project and you have two separate projects. You might try to write a powershell script that would start both apps for you.Refer to http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/run-multiple-asp-net-core-projects-using-dotnet-run-command/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge No.

I would like to know why you want to run 2 or more web project like this? When you created 2 separate project for isolation.

You can setup multiple startup project through visual studio or command. If there is a way to run multiple project like this then both project will run under same Application Domain and When your one application get crash then another application also stop.

Comment: Yes,I need both services to go down if one crashes.

Comment: Why one service project for both apps?

Comment: FYI..If you are looking modular framework just look Orchard Core framework https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrQaKv2mxFU&feature=youtu.be